# single sign on (sso) laravel

Tags: php, laravel, single-sign-on, saml

I have three different laravel websites, I want to make user sign in at one website then he will be automatically logged in to the other two websites.
eg. if you logged in at your [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com) then open [stackexchange](https://stackexchange.com/) you will be logged in with StackOverflow account.
I have tried many packages but they end with infinite exceptions or they simply not working.
Most of the packages based on SAML, I have no idea why it did not work with me?
I do not know what I miss?
Is there any config for this to work?
**I am using laravel 5.6. All the apps are on the same server.**

I have tried many solutions based on SAML, OpenID and share session, but all of them did not work with me.
I do not know if I miss something.
[this is the last example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36009319/6186572) I tried and it did not work

this is my code

SITE A

```
$site_b = 'http://s_sesstion_2.test/';
Route::get('/', function (Request $request) use ($site_b) {
    $session_id = Session::getId();
    try {
        $http = new Client();
        $response = $http->post($site_b . 'api/sessions/server', [
            'form_params' => [
                'session_id' => $session_id,
            ],
            'headers' => [
                'Accept' => 'application/json',
            ]
        ]);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        dd($e->getMessage());
    }
    return view('welcome');
});
```

SITE B  (route/api.php)

```
    Route::post('/sessions/server', function (Request $request) {
    Storage::disk('local')->put('file.txt', $request->get('session_id'));
});
```

SITE B  (route/web.php)

```
    Route::get('/', function () {
    $session_id = Storage::disk('local')->get('file.txt');
    Session::setId($session_id);
    Session::start();
    //return Session::getId();// will return the same session id
    return \auth()->user();//this should return the auth user but it did not!!
});
```

All I want is to sign in at **site A** then open **site B** I will be signed in. **I will accept any solution achieve that purpose**

Comment: Do this websites share database?

Comment: @Kyslik yes, they share the same database

Comment: You're expected to attempt a solution and show us what you've tried. SSO is a really broad topic with many many ways to solve and we can't just speculate what would work best for your case.

Comment: @apokryfos I have tried many packages based on SAML and it did not work, and I have tried to share session but did not work either

Comment: We can't know why things didn't work if you don't share what you've tried and by that I mean the actual code you've tried.

Comment: @apokryfos I added code blocks from the last example I have tried. and the link to verfied answer

Comment: @MoauyaMeghari - you can see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51435654/how-to-setup-saml-to-mutiple-domain#51468770 answer from @n-b .  You can setup `simplasamlphp` or other saml library 'lightsaml' etc.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40458694/4075877 this solution may help.

Answer (score 22):

I implemented an SSO solution without using SAML. I'll share my solution here, hope it helps.

### Single Sign On

One application runs as the main authentication server at `auth.domain`. Other applications run in different domains `app1.domain`, `app2.domain`, ...

Every user is linked with **SSO tokens**. These tokens have very short expiration times. All authentication processes (signing in, resetting passwords, registering, ...) happen **only** in `auth.domain` application.

When a user visits any applications, for example, `app-1.domain`:

1. Redirect user to `auth.domain/login`.
2. If the user logged in our system before, continue at **step 6**.
3. Show the sign in form, waiting for valid input.
4. Generate a new **SSO token** with the expiration time less than 3 minutes.
5. Attach the `auth.domain` remember me cookie to the response.
6. Return a redirection response to the `app-1.domain/sso/{sso_token}`.
7. `app-1.domain` application read the database. If the **SSO token** is valid and does not expire, find the user associated to that token.
8. `app-1.domain` authenticates the user found in the previous step with `Auth::login($user)` method.
9. `app-1.domain` clear the received **SSO token** from the database.

After this step, the user is authenticated to `app-1.domain`.

### Session sharing

All shared session variables should be saved to databases. I implemented a new session driver:

- Keep the list of shared session variable names
- When reading/writing to sessions, check the name of the session variable. If that name is the previous list, read/write the value from the database. Otherwise, use the private session of each own application.

Comment: Nice solution! How do you handle the logout?

Comment: When users log out, I redirect them to the `auth.domain/logout` to clear the common session then redirect him/her back to the original site.

Comment: Hi @HieuLe , may i know on *Step 4*, does that mean we'll encounter every 301 redirection whenever the 3 minute token has expired? or we can do it on http/ajax request to refresh the token?

Comment: I've been trying to use ````Auth::login($user)```` but I get ````BadMethodCallException: Method Illuminate\Auth\RequestGuard::loginUsingId does not exist```` please have a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66465177/laravel-6-how-to-autologin-user-in-a-different-laravel-application-without-pass

Answer (score 1):

If your both applications share the same databases then you can follow the approach :

-> In your database , create a default session id that will be marked as false initially

-> Now as soon as user login to any of the site, generate a new hash and replace it with the default value.

---

**optionally**

-> You can also save the hash on browser local storage with hash as a key and null as value.

---

-> Now when user is logging into/switching to any of the site, check that hash
-> If the hash matches the default, show the login page else show the profile page.

---

My answer is valid only if you are using common database for login else you need mapping for this.

---

Alternatively you can use cookies to store hash and can access them in cross domain.
Can find example at [Cross-Domain Cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342140/cross-domain-cookies)
By @ludovic