# Best way to implement single sign on in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, authentication, single-sign-on, saml, saml-2.0

I'm building an application that has a core hub, say it's called musictickets.com

We'll provide a subdomain (bandname1.musictickets.com) to bands on which only their content will display, which they can mask using a CNAME record to be part of their domain - so tickets.bandname1.com

There would be multiple bands using the platform so you'll end up with pages at

tickets.bandname1.com
tickets.bandname2.com

etc.

I'd like a user who registers at tickets.bandname1.com to be automatically logged in on every site that uses the service, including the parent, musictickets.com . They should be able to register/login using OAuth or directly via form based authentication.

I'm looking at SAML (specifically https://github.com/aacotroneo/laravel-saml2) as one option, but want to throw this out to the wider community for comment.

I've also looked at using token based SSO as described here ([single sign on (sso) laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51532814/single-sign-on-sso-laravel)) and running an auth server (which I may do in any case). Alternatively, I've looked at using iframes to provide the functionality which feels quick but dirty.

As I understand it, I wouldn't be able to use cookies (for an API key for instance) because whilst all of the content will be displayed via a subdomain, the CNAME would make it a different domain.

Does anyone have any thoughts on the best strategy?

Comment: did you find a solution for your query. I'm looking for the same