# Laravel 6: How to autologin user in a different Laravel application without password

Tags: laravel, authentication, autologin

I'm working on a Laravel 6 application where users can sign in using the API (front is in VueJS) and I have no issues with it. Now I have another Laravel 6 app on a different server. The scenario is: the user is going to sign in through the first app and click a button to navigate to the second app (also an API with VueJS frontend). I want to automatically log the user in without having to sign in again. I tried to test a sample code

In routes/api.php

```
Route::group(['namespace' => 'Api', 'middleware' => 'guest'], function () {
   Route::post('manual-login', 'ManualLoginController'); // use __invoke method
```

The controller

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

$userId = $request->user_id;
Auth::loginUsingId($userId);
```

$userId is a uuid field with the value `37aca7b3-7c6b-3745-9b54-5ced6cc3216e` and I also tried with integer user id but I get

```
BadMethodCallException: Method Illuminate\Auth\RequestGuard::loginUsingId does not exist
```

How can I use `Auth::loginUsingId` or `Auth::login` to automatically sign in the user in the app without entering the password? If there's a better method I'd appreciate an explanation.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Is it correct Auth class that you called ?

Comment: ````use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;````

Comment: https://laravel.com/api/6.x/search.html?search=loginUsingId

Comment: Id looks not good to me it can be simple integer (mixed)  -- Auth::loginUsingId(55)

Comment: In the system it's uuid not id and can't be changed right now for other reasons and I already tried an integer id but got the same error

Comment: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/6.x/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Auth.php 
     --
Look its also on line 17 base is defined different place

Comment: what happens you only : use Auth;   not as a Illuminate\Support\Facades\auth

Comment: @MetByrdy I already tried ````use Auth;```` but I get the same error

Comment: Route::post('manual-login', 'ManualLoginController');  this might need @index or a method also

Comment: @MetByrdy I use ````__invoke```` and can test the data and check if user exists or not and it's working fine no need to add a method